# Derivatives of Multivariables with Chain Rule

Tags: calculus

$\frac{dz}{dt}$ of $z = (x+y)e^y$, $x = 6t$, $y = 1-t^2$

I figured the formula for this was $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt}$

For the first term I calculated: $6e^y$

For the 2nd term I calculated $(xe^y + ye^y + e^y)(-2t)$ or $e^y(x + y + 1)(-2t)$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial of $z$ with respect to $x$ is $$e^y=e^{1-t^2}$$The partial of $z$ with respect to $y$ is $$e^y(x+y+1)=(2+6t-t^2)e^{1-t^2}$$Then $x'(t)=6$ and $y'(t)=-2t$.  Finally, $$z'(t)=6e^{1-t^2}+(-2t)[2+6t-t^2]e^{1-t^2}=2e^{1-t^2}[t^3-6t^2-2t+3]$$